# why does integration allow multiple solutions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

When integrating $\frac 1x$ or $\frac{n}{nx}$ where n is a constant both produce $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(nx)$.
Does this mean $\ln(x)$ is equal to $\ln(nx)$?
Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: How are you getting log nx? Are you sure you are doing a definite integral

Comment: The general antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $ln(x)+c$. You can write $c=ln(exp(c))$. Since $exp(c)$ is also a constant, you could just 'replace' it with $k$, and by logarithm laws that's just $ln(kx)$ (where $kx>0$).

Answer (score 6):

$$\ln nx = \ln x +\ln n $$

The solutions only differ by a constant, which is allowed. ($\ln n$ is a constant as $n$ is a constant)

Comment: Perhaps add that $\ln n$ is a constant.  To help beginners.